# Removing group of random characters

Tags: batch-rename

Ok so I have these files

File1 (37362717)
File2 (29190171)
File3 (35515714)

How would a script look to remove the (*) portion of the name?

Comment: Are "FileX" part of the file names? what are the expected output exactly? Are you in Windows or Linux system?

Comment: FileX is the name I want to keep. Expected outcome is to keep the FileX and eliminate the (xxxxxxxx) portion of every name. Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use powershell, use this command in the directory containing all your files that need rename:

```
Get-ChildItem File* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace " \(\d+\)", "" }
```

This command renames all files whose name starts with "File" in current directory so that the "space and then parentheses with numbers inside" (`\(\d+\)`) part will be removed.

Check example 4 in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6#examples) to understand how this command works.

Comment: @JohnathanSimpson You need to open a powershell window and change directory to the target directory. Can you run `Get-ChildItem File*` in that directory and see if it prints anything?

Comment: @JohnathanSimpson So it means that there is no file whose name starts with `File`. To change directory you need to enter command `cd d:\my\target\directory` (change to your target directory). Can you share the output of command `Get-ChildItem` at the target directory to make sure the `File (1234567)` or similar files show up?

Comment: Ok so fix the confusion they are not called file they are game names ie Chrono Trigger (xxxxxxccc), Final Fantasy VII (xxxxxxccc)

Comment: @JohnathanSimpson then removing the `File*` part will work as expected (remove all the parentheses that contain numbers) in file names: `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace " \(\d+\)", "" }`

Comment: @JohnathanSimpson You can accept the answer if it solves your problem.